# Did Abraham use a flint knife for circumcision and/or for the akedah?

Tags: brit-milah, abraham, binding-of-isaac, yehoshua-joshua, exodus

I've seen it queried why Tzipporah and Joshua use/are commanded to use flint knives for the circumcisions they perform (Exodus 4:25, Joshua 5:3) when they had access to metal (bronze) knives in that era.

Usually the answer tend to flint possibly being sharper or cleaner than metalwork could achieve then, or a deliberate reference to the tradition being old and a religious matter, so the oldest method was preferred:

https://booksnthoughts.com/unusual-bible-interpretations-joshua-5-part-1/

http://jandyongenesis.blogspot.com/2011/11/why-zipporah-used-flint-knife.html

https://www.artofishi.com/flint-knives-bible/

With regard to the latter, does any commentary actually discuss what specific tool/material Abraham used to circumcise himself and his household? Bronze, flint, etc?
Similarly, does any make mention of the material of the knife he might have used on Isaac in the akedah?

Comment: This *sefer* (https://www.google.co.il/books/edition/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%98%D7%A8/MP4ZAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D+%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94+%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9F+%D7%A9%D7%9C+%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8&dq=%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D+%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94+%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9F+%D7%A9%D7%9C+%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8&printsec=frontcover) seems to think that the term סכין used in reference to the *akeidah* indicates a metal knife.

Comment: Incidentally, the observation that flint knives can do better surgery than metal is still current - https://edition.cnn.com/2015/04/02/health/surgery-scalpels-obsidian/index.html.

Comment: Sadly my Hebrew is terrible, so I can't read the sefer, but thanks!

That article seems to be about obsidian though, not flint? 
I guess the same principle might apply to flint instruments, but obsidian doesn't seem historically to have been widely used in the Middle East.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is obvious that the word צור translates strictly to the current scientifically defined flint. Instead I would postulate that it translates to "a sharp rock". As this article (http://www.quartzpage.de/flint.html) points out, flint, obsidian and quartz were traditionally used as cutting tools. I do not mean to say that צור specifically means obsidian, but I also wouldn't say that it couldn't mean either obsidian or quartz, in addition to flint.

Comment: True, but again, there seems to have been less historical use of obsidian in the Middle East, so flint is more likely (quartz seems to be a middle ground, but still probably less common than flint). 

A metal knife for the akedah seems reasonable through (since you don't need surgical precision or hygiene if you are aiming to kill).